# Are Qur'an 16:4, 22:5, 18:37 and 35:11 wrong because man was not only created from a sperm drop?

Tags: quran, tafseer, science

All of these verses ([16:4](https://quran.com/16/4), [22:5](https://quran.com/22/5), [18:37](https://quran.com/18/37), [35:11](https://quran.com/35/11))  have a common sentence ----

".... and We created man from a sperm drop......"

But the zygote is formed by the FUSION of sperm and ovum. The ovum also has 50% of the contribution.

So isn't this verse wrong as it clearly states that man was created FROM a sperm drop.

Also there is a similar question like this in stack exchange already asked, but that was deactivated also there wasn't a legit answer there.

That's why I asked this question anew but I didn't copycat, I had this question in me before I even saw his post and I really want a good answer as this is troubling my faith.

Comment: There are hadith that explicitly mention the role of the ovum, e.g. [this](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/3) one and [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/32) one, in the second one سبقة is translatable to either temporal precedence or dominance.

Comment: @Uma But the vaginal discharge ofa women doesn't have any significant contribution in the production of a zygote, it doesn't contain any gamete, it just prevents that area from infection and keeps the vagina clean, so that hadith seems controversial

Comment: You are assuming that the sentence 'We created man from a sperm drop' negates the presence of any other constituent that may have been there. In other words, you are reading the above sentence as 'We created man *(just)* from a sperm drop'. That is why the above question arose in your mind.

Comment: maybe translation is incorrect. does "nutfat" really mean "sperm drop"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of Qur'an verses that talk about what man was created from:

> Created man from a clinging substance.
> <sub>[Qur'an 96:2](https://quran.com/96/2)</sub>
>
> ... created from water a human being ...
> <sub>[Qur'an 25:54](https://quran.com/25/54)</sub>
>
> ... create man out of clay from an altered black mud ...
> <sub>[Qur'an 15:26](https://quran.com/15/26)</sub>
>
> ... He created you from dust ...
> <sub>[Qur'an 30:20](https://quran.com/30/20)</sub>
>
> ... He has produced you from the earth ...
> <sub>[Qur'an 11:61](https://quran.com/11/61)</sub>
>
> ... created man from a sperm-drop ...
> <sub>[Qur'an 16:4](http://created%20man%20from%20a%20sperm-drop)</sub>

We don't expect man to be e.g. 100% made out of water; it's just an important element in man's creation.  Likewise for the others.

In addition to the above, there's ahadith that indicate the Prophet was aware that the process is more complicated then "sperm => man", such as:

> ... a human being is put together in the womb of the mother in forty days, and then he becomes a clot of thick blood for a similar period, and then a piece of flesh for a similar period ...
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 3208](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/19)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=76&verse=2 : there is said "nutfatin amshajin" where nutfa is what is usually translated as "sperm drop" and "amshaj" is adjective meaning "mixed", so it means something like "mixed drop". a translation from https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/76/2/default.htm :

> We have created the human from a seed that is mixed, We test him, so
>   We made him hear and see.

"nutfa" is translated in baranov's arabic-russian dictionary as 1) clear water 2) drop 3) semen, sperm. verb natafa is translated as 1) drop; slowly flow down; 2) ... 3) ... .

Answer (score 0):

bismillahir-rahmanir-rahim, Nutfah has often been understood and translated as sperm-drop, although this is not necessarily the meaning of nutfah, but just drop. Plus the meaning of the word amshaj is mixed, so "nutfatin amshajin" would be a mixed drop= male and female ingredients combined. Further the Quran says it comes from "between the loins and the ribs".  Biology knows, that the fluid in an ejaculation comes not only from the testicles, but to  a great part from upper parts. Plus, it could also be a sign for the  ovaries, because aren´t they somewhere between the loins and the ribs? It is not the Quran´s faults, if patriarchal thinking of scholars and translators always omit the female side.

Answer (score -1):

**Absolutely Not**... The Quran is Right

Bismillah , Me as a medical student Know that *Man contain XY sex Chromosome and Chromosome (Y) is only available in Sperm and quran says*

> We created Man from Sperm drop that 's Right man can never be created from Ovum as Ovum lack Y Chromosome and TDF factor Too.